# C# SQL Method to Oracle

Tags: c#, sql, oracle

I need to rewrite a number of methods to work with a clients Oracle database.  I have it so it will work with simple select statements, but am having trouble finding out how to declare a variable, setting the info in that variable, and then inserting it into a table; inside of the command text like i do for SQL.  Here is a simplified version of what i have for the SQL version of the method.
Any help will be greatly appreciated.
Thank you in advance.

```
public void SQLOracleQuestion(int numID)
    {
        Exception exception = null;
        try
        {
            StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
            sb.Append(" Declare @item varchar(5), @id int ");
            sb.Append(" set @id = " + numID.ToString() + " ");
            sb.Append(" SELECT @item = MAX(Cast(DOCID as int)) FROM Table1 WHERE ID = @id ");
            sb.Append(" SET @item = CAST(Cast(isnull(@item, 0) as integer) + 1 as varchar(12)) ");
            sb.Append(" INSERT INTO Table2 (ID, item, time) ");
            sb.Append(" Select @id, @item, '" + DateTime.Now.ToString() + "' " );

            SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(sb.ToString(), _conn);
            cmd.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
            _conn.Open();

            cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            exception = ex;
        }
        finally
        {
            if (_conn.State != ConnectionState.Closed)
                _conn.Close();

            if (exception != null)
            {
                throw exception;
            }
        }

    }
```

Comment: What exactly is wrong with your code? Whats the error?

Comment: Ok, so i looked at your SQL and its not even valid SQL. Forget about the C# and get valid SQL working first then add it to your code.

Comment: First it does work it was just a typo with 'declare'.  it doesn't error with SQL i need to make it work with an oracle database.  I don't have a lot of experience with oracle.  we don't even have an Oracle database to test with our selves, we have to test it on the clients. It is not the most ideal situation.   Can you just write the command text the same with oracle as with MS SQL?  I have been searching online for the last day or so and it must be so basic of what I want to do that no one has tutorials on it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you dont have an Oracle database then you can create an online schema and run queries using this Oracle website and test your queries.

https://livesql.oracle.com/apex/f?p=590:1:106725498548660::NO:::

Oracle PL SQL is slightly different than T SQL.

How to declare variables in Oracle:

```
DECLARE
    MyNumber NUMBER(19,0) := 0;
    MyString varchar2(100) := 'hello';
```

How to put a value into your variable:

```
SELECT MyColumn INTO MyNumber FROM MyTable;
```

How to use a declared variable. No @ is required:

```
SELECT * FROM MyTable WHERE MyColumn = MyNumber;
```

How to Insert in oracle using regular data or a variable. 2 methods. Note the DUAL table in the second method. This is a special table for dual this sort of stuff. Google it.

```
INSERT INTO MyTable (MyColumn, MyColumn2, MyColumn3) VALUES (MyNumber, 1, 1234);
INSERT INTO MyTable (MyColumn, MyColumn2, MyColumn3) SELECT MyNumber, 1, 1234 FROM DUAL;
```

Manually change a variable:

```
MyNumber := MyNumber + 1;
```

Comment: Thank you very much.  This is exactly what I needed.